# ImportError: No module named vanilla_project.settings.dev

Tags: django, apache2, wsgi, forum

Apache. Django. Forum: http://django-machina.readthedocs.io
install with git clone and migrate

Why apache dont see settings.dev file ?

apache2.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/django-machina/example_projects/vanilla/wsgi.py

WSGIPythonPath /var/www/django-machina/example_projects

<Directory /var/www/django-machina/example_projects>
        <Files wsgi.py>
                Require all granted
        </Files>
</Directory>

Alias /static/ /var/www/django-machina/example_projects/static/
<Location "/static/">
    Options -Indexes
</Location>
```

Comment: Why do you want to use the dev settings in production?

Comment: Based on your path to the WSGI script file using ``vanilla``, rather than ``vanilla_project``, then the ``DJANGO_SETTINGS`` variable in ``wsgi.py`` is not set correctly. Or have you changed names and what you show isn't actually what you are using, therefore making it harder for anyone to debug, as this version has mistakes?

Comment: BTW, you should also use daemon mode of mod_wsgi. Don't use embedded mode.